# Music player with custom metadata

Tags: music-player, metadata

I'm looking for a music player with a particular feature:
i wish to choose and edit, for each songs, custom meta tags with support of metadata type (i.e. rating, enum chooser, number)..
i.e. :

- **quality**      -> rating
- **performance**  -> rating
- **target**       -> dropdown with enumed values
- .. and any other customs

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not possible natively, in [Quod Libet](http://quodlibet.readthedocs.org) this would be a fairly simple plugin if you know Python (or can convince someone to write it for you).

We keep a good eye on the [Github feature requests](https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet/issues), and it's possible someone in the QL community (it's been going >10 years now) has done something similar...

Hope that helps.